# What chemical equation proves that KHCO3 can extinguish a fire?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In a dry powder fire extinguisher, there is a chemical known as $\ce{KHCO3}$ and I was wondering how $\ce{KHCO3}$ works in a chemical equation to extinguish the fire.

Comment: $$\ce{KHCO3 -> KOH + CO2}$$

Comment: Please also see [this answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/65818/27806) which contains a subsection and a reference for how $\ce{NaHCO3}$ works. It is more that just the decomposition yielding $\ce{CO2}$; surpressing chain reactions tying up radicals is also key here (and heat of vaporisation and heat capacity).

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42130/potassium-vs-sodium-bicarbonate-in-fire-fighting

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_bicarbonate) Wikipedia entry:

> Decomposition of the bicarbonate occurs between 100 and 120 °C (212
>   and 248 °F):
>
> $$\ce{2 KHCO3 → K2CO3 + CO2 + H2O}, \Delta H>0$$

So, you produce a nonflammable powder and two nonflammable gases, and you absorb heat from the fire in an endothermic reaction.

The picture here is more complex than just a chemical equation however. The $\ce{KHCO3}$ also acts as an energy-absorbing material and provides a solid surface on which free radicals can be destroyed.

Comment: Tried \DeltaH and it came out bad.  What was wrong?

Comment: Thx @OscarLanzi .

Comment: Thx @NilayGhosh.